# Use artifactory without remote npm repository

Tags: npm, offline, artifactory

I'm working in an environment where artifactory does not have internet access. We would like to use artifactory as a npm registry and host. Is it possible to upload external dependencies and their transitive dependencies?

For example: I'm on a computer with internet access and downloaded webpack and all its dependencies using npm install. Now I go to a different network with artifactory access and want to upload my node_modules Folder. Does that work somehow?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Artifactory's proxy/caching features, it can also host multiple local repositories (such as npm repositories) in it. This basically means that you can create an [npm local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-LocalNpmRegistry) in Artifactory and deploy any npm *.tgz packages (your dependencies) into this repository and Artifactory will generate the relevant metadata for your client. All you'll need to do is to deploy the relevant packages and configur your npm clients to resolve from Artifactory.

Comment: How to download webpack and its dependencies as a tgz without manually resolving all its dependencies?

Comment: @daniel , my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43673807/1021714) solves this problem if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made an node module that should help with this problem.
You give it a list of packages that you want downloaded and it will download the packages with all dependencies as a tar.gz. It will then save them in the original npm folder structure, and create a tar.gz with everything inside.

You can then take the tar.gz with all your dependencies and deploy it to Artifactory using the deploy wizard.
[image: Artifactory Deploy]

When you deploy, select the checkbox "Deploy as Bundle Artifact". This will extract the tar.gz of packages and load them into the npm repository. Artifactory will read the package.json of all packages, and will load the relevant information, allowing you to pull packages with npm.

The package is called [package-bundle](https://github.com/alexbrazier/package-bundle), and can be downloaded from npm using `npm install -g package-bundle`

To download packages you can run the command `pb bluebird express@1.0.1`, which will fetch the specified packages, and all the required dependencies.